# Vim maths syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, markdown, vim-syntax-highlighting, multimarkdown

I'm trying to improve the syntax highlighting of maths in markdown documents.

Multimarkdown uses brackets `\\[ .. \\]` and `\\( .. \\)` to indicate display and inline math respectively. I want to highlight the contents of these with TeX.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
syntax include @tex syntax/tex.vim
syn region displaymaths matchgroup=mkdMaths start = "\\\\\[" end="\\\\\]" contains=@tex
syn region inlinemaths matchgroup=mkdMaths start = "\\\\(" end="\\\\)" contains=@tex
hi def link mkdMaths SpecialComment
```

The problem is that what is inside the brackets isn't picked up as maths by tex.vim because it isn't enclosed in `$ .. $`. Is there a way I can get around this? I think it is the texMath group in syntax/tex.vim that I want to use here.

Is there some way I can force the contents of the brackets to be interpreted as Tex maths?

Comment: What happens if you replace `contains=@tex` with `contains=@texMathZoneGroup`?

Comment: works, thanks. the documentation does say that this will work, but it didn't occur to me after reading it several times!

Comment: Ah, nice, so my hunch was right. I've added a slightly more detailed answer. Please accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:syntax include @tex syntax/tex.vim` gives you a `@tex` syntax cluster to use in regions containing Tex, but you actually want to refer to a particular cluster existing in tex.vim, `@texMathZoneGroup`.

Since there is no nesting of syntax clusters, you can just directly refer to it via `contains=@texMathZoneGroup`.

Comment: For anyone using vimtex in 2021, use `contains=@texClusterMath`.

Answer (score 0):

```
syntax include syntax/tex.vim
syn region displaymaths matchgroup=mkdMaths start = "\\\\\[" end="\\\\\]" contains=@texMathZoneGroup
syn region inlinemaths matchgroup=mkdMaths start = "\\\\(" end="\\\\)" contains=@texMathZoneGroup
hi def link mkdMaths SpecialComment
```

The vim documentation (`:help syn-include`) actually states this quite clearly (although could perhaps do with an example):

> If top-level syntax items in the included syntax file are to be
>     contained within a region in the including syntax, you can use the
>     ":syntax include" command:

```
n:sy[ntax] include [@{grouplist-name}] {file-name}
```

If you want to include a specific top-level syntax item 'foo' from the included syntax file, you need to have `contains=@foo` in the `syn region` command.

> All syntax items declared in the included file will have the
>     "contained" flag added.  In addition, if a group list is specified,
>     all top-level syntax items in the included file will be added to
>     that list.

So the `@tex` grouplist-name in my question didn't need to be specified. If I were to have larger regions of TeX in my documents though, this would need specifying as it gives access to the namespace of the included syntax file, such that `contains=@tex` will highlight the entire region according to all of the rules of the included syntax file.